# django pytest - unable to create testdb

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

I have trouble creating a test DB and gives error as there is no database found. Im really not sure what is wrong and why database is not creating

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testing.test_settings
addopts = --nomigrations --cov=. --cov-report=html
```

test_settings.py

```
from settings import *

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3_testing'),
        }
    }
```

During my tests I run the command as `py.test --reuse-db` but still I dont find db created

test.py

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestUsers:

    def test_user(self,client):
        response = client.get("/test", follow=True)
        assert len(response.context['list'])==1
```

this throws me AssertionError and error is 
[image]

**Any help in creating a test databse would be helpful**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that pytest.ini will pass environment variable.
Try running like this

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testing.test_settings py.test --reuse-db
```

Also I hope you know that that the name of created db is generated like [`'test_' + DATABASES['NAME']`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEST_NAME) or taken from [`TEST`  dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924205432/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)

And in your screenshot failing test is `test_with_client` but you are showing us `test_user` test's code.